# Make fgets save characters to a variable in C

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop, conditional-statements, fgets

I have this small program:

```
char buffer[10] = "0"
while (buffer == "0"){
 fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);

if(buffer == "1\n") do this
if(buffer == "2\n") do that
}
```

However, when I press 1 or 2 (or anything else for that matter), nothing happens.
What am I missing?

Comment: Use `strcmp` to compare strings.

Comment: You can't use `==` to compare strings in C - use strcmp instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`while (buffer == "0")`

Here , i think , you are expect for

`while(strcmp(buffer,"0")==0)`.// You can change condition

Answer (score 1):

change to

```
char buffer[10] = "0"
while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin){
    if(strcmp(buffer, "1\n")==0)
        ;//do this
    if(strcmp(buffer, "2\n")==0)
        ;//do that
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have already told you that you can't compare strings with `==`. In your case, where you want to write a menu, you might convert the buffer to a number first with `sscanf` or `atoi`.

Here's a simple implementation of such a menu:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char buffer[10];
    int done = 0;

    while (!done) {
        int option = 0;

        puts("1. Do this");
        puts("2. Do that");
        puts("3. Quit\n");

        if (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) == NULL) break;
        if (sscanf(buffer, "%d", &option) < 1) option = 0;

        switch (option) {
        case 1:
            puts("Done this.\n");
            break;

        case 2:
            puts("Done that.\n");
            break;

        case 3:
            done = 1;
            break;

        default:
            puts("Please enter one of 1, 2, 3\n");
        }
    }

    puts("Bye!");
    return 0;
}
```